# How to count each element number in array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three word in array 'good','is','good'

```
let arr = ['good','is','good']
```

In arr,the word 'good' show 2 times,the word 'is' show 1 time.And I use this code to count show times

```
arr.reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[next] = prev[next] + 1 || 1;
  return prev;
}, []);
```

The result is `[good:2,is:1]`

But Here is important,What I want is this format: `[good:1,is:1,good:2]`

The `arr[0]` good,first time show,value = 1,the `arr[2]` good,second time show,value = 2

How to get this format?

Comment: `[good:2,is:1]` and `[good:1,is:1,good:2]` are not valid JavaScript. Do you mean `{good:2,is:1}` and `{good:1,is:1,good:2}`? That's also not possible. You can't have duplicate keys in an object. Or do you mean `[{good:2},{is:1}]` and `[{good:1},{is:1},{good:2}]`?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: arr.reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[next] = prev[next] + 1 || 1;
  return prev;
}, []); this code is found in internet.It get this strange result [good:2,is:1]. What I want is [{good:1},{is:1},{good:2}] this result

Comment: `[good:2,is:1]` is not possible in JavaScript. What have you tried to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the counting code in a `map`:

```js
let arr = ['good','is','good']

const result = arr.map((() => {
  const count = {};
  return el => {
    count[el] = count[el] + 1 || 1;
    return {[el]: count[el]};
  }
})())
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this works.Thank you very very much!